# Why does the second "a" have different value than the first "a"?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the difference of two characters.
My problem is when I input the 2nd character it gives a different value even if the character is just the same as the first input:

Example below. I input "a" as first char and then "a" again for the second but it gives different value

```
int main(){

    
    char* flet;
    char* slet;
   
    printf("Input first character:");
    scanf("%c", &flet);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Input Second character:");
    scanf("%c", &slet);

    printf("First Char is \"%c\" and Second Char is \"%c\".", flet,slet);

    DiffofChar(flet,slet);
}

void DiffofChar(char* letter1, char* letter2){
    int theDiff;
    theDiff = letter1 - letter2;
    printf("The difference of %c (%d) and %c (%d) is %d.", letter1, letter1, letter2, letter2, theDiff);
}
```

Output:

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nachs, save time.  Enable all warnings to rapidly get compiler feedback that a problem exists involving `scanf("%c", &flet);`.

Comment: You should urgently turn up your compiler warnings. For gcc you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It should tell you about argument type mismatch for `printf` when you pass a `char*` while a `int` is expected. And for `scanf` when `char*` is expected whily you pass `char**`. And for using function `DiffofChar` without prototype. After you fixed missing prototype, it will tell you about passing wrong parameter types to that function as well. Don't waste time! Listen to your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
char* flet;
char* slet;

printf("Input first character:");
scanf("%c", &flet);
```

At best, the above will cast the character value typed (`a`) into a pointer and that address (`0x61 == 'a'`) will just be a pointer value for an invalid memory location.

The fix is to declare the variables as just type `char`. You still pass &flet and &slet to the scanf functions.

```
char flet;
char slet;

printf("Input first character:");
scanf("%c", &flet);
```